# $f_n$ converges to $f$ implies $f_n’$ converges to $f’$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

I have a question regarding the validity of this proof:

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to $f$. Assume also that $f_n’$ converges pointwise. Then, $f_n’$ converges to $f’$.

We must show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $|f_n’(a)-f’(a)|<\epsilon$. Expanding out using the definition of the derivative:

$$|f'_n(a)-f'(a)|=|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(a)-f(x)+f(a)}{x-a}|=|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(x)-f(x)-f_n(a)-f(a)}{x-a}|$$

$$\leq |\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(x)-f(x)}{x-a}|+|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(a)-f(a)}{x-a}|$$

Then, because we supposed $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, we have that there exists some $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $n\geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon|x-a|}{2}$, thus:

$$|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(x)-f(x)}{x-a}|+|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f_n(a)-f(a)}{x-a}|<2|\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\epsilon|x-a|}{2(x-a)}|=\epsilon$$

Thus, $f'_n(x)\to f'(x)$ if $f'_n(x)$ converges and $f_n(x)\to f(x)$.

I'm mostly worried about the step involving a definition of $\epsilon$ that is dependent on $x$ and $a$. It doesn't feel quite right because it doesn't take into account the limit right away. Maybe this is fine. If it is not the case, how would one complete the proof?

Comment: By "$f_n$ converges to $f$" do you mean pointwise convergence, uniform convergence, or what type of convergence? And, yes, you have a problem with your definition of $N$, because it depends on $x$. You would need to show you can find an $N$ that works for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: Ah that’s right. So I could use the fact that the derivative limit is defined to essentially work towards that idea of $N$ holds when $x$ is close enough to $a$?

Comment: If you're dealing with pointwise convergence, the statement is false. For a counterexample, consider the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$$

Comment: But if it converges uniformly it is true?

Comment: Yes, if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, and $f'_n$ converges uniformly, then $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$. Sorry, I should have clarified that in my earlier comment.

Comment: What is “it” in your last comment?

Comment: First mistake: How do you know that $f$ is differentiable?